# How to read & handle data from a dynamically made sql table

Tags: c#, sql, .net, class

tl;dr is there a way to create dynamical classes or objects from a sql table whos columns you do not know the name or amount of, that later can be used for sorting, searching and so on?

I have a website that has various projects you can choose from, they are all basically identical just that they have different data and users which are split up based on the project ID. Like projects usually are.

However one thing I have is that one of the tables is created dynamically with code, the table is called projectTable_(id number here). And the columns is based on what you choose in a input form. In this form you can choose the name of the columns, what datatype, size and so on. With this I create the table with the custom columns.

I also create a description table to know what columns that's inside this project, this table is called projectTable_(id number here)_desc

The description table can look like this :
[image: Description Table]

While the dynamically made table looks like this
[image]

(These are cutouts and not the full tables)

So the tables are being created fine and I have all the information about what the columns are called and so on.

This description table is always the same(discounting the data within) so I can create a class for the description table were I can store all the data.

But for the dynamically made table I am not sure how I am supposed to handle the data

Right now my C# code to get the dynamically made tables' data looks like this :

```
    public static List<List<string>> getAllFromCustomTable(int projectID)
    {
        string tableName = string.Format("projectTable_{0}", projectID);
        string sql = string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", tableName);

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);

        List<List<string>> lstCustomTableData = new List<List<string>>();
        List<tableDescription> lstTableDescription = tableDescriptionModel.getAllTableDescription(projectID);
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                #region reader

                List<string> lstCustomTableDataItem = new List<string>();

                if (reader["id"] != DBNull.Value)
                    lstCustomTableDataItem.Add(reader["id"].ToString());
                else
                    lstCustomTableDataItem.Add("");

                foreach (tableDescription tableDescription in lstTableDescription)
                {
                    if (reader[tableDescription.columnName] != DBNull.Value)
                        lstCustomTableDataItem.Add(reader[tableDescription.columnName].ToString());
                    else
                        lstCustomTableDataItem.Add("");
                }

                lstCustomTableData.Add(lstCustomTableDataItem);

                #endregion
            }
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
            connection.Dispose();
        }

        return lstCustomTableData;
    }
```

And this actually works. But now I just have a List of a list of strings that contains all the data.

But basically I want to be able to sort, search and even convert it to json, but I have no idea how I should do this since I don't have a class to use for it(since the columns names are made dynamically)

I know what the column names are from the table description table but that's it.

But basically 2 - I've pretty much only used classes for everything and I don't know what to do when I don't have a class available. 
Are there dynamical classes or objects that you can use for cases like this?

Also I know that this code is open for SQL injections but this is the only part of it that is open for it and these functions are only available in a limited area with high user roles requirements

Thanks for your time

Comment: The classic way: `DataTable` filled by a `DataAdapter`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Haven't really used it that much before but I'll look into it